# Samsung Galaxy S3 CSS Bug (only S3)

Tags: html, css

i have some weird bug which appears only on Samsung S3 (iPhone, S2 and few others works good).
Problem is when i click on search field in header or in sidebar, all text gets centered and items gets aligned on right side.

Looks like :focus event have text-align and other properties but it doesn't...double checked all code. Anyone have any idea what's happening?

This is when i click on input field:
http://ewizz.me/bugs/bug1.jpg

Here is live site: http://testing.visuallemon.com

Thanks!